# How to insert elements into shared pointer of std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, stdmap

I can insert with map like this:

```
std::map<int, int> testMap;
testMap.insert(std::make_pair(0, 1));
```

But if I surround the map with shared pointer like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, int>> testSharedMap;
testSharedMap->insert(std::make_pair(0, 1));
```

It doesn't work. I get a runtime error.

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
_Scary was nullptr. occurred
```

How can I use the `std::map` when it was surrounded by `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: you need to allocate it first. it defaults to null.

Comment: The "surrounded by" terminology is strange. A pointer points to things; it does not "surround" things. Saying that `testSharedMap` surrounds a map is equivalent to saying that `str` surrounds a character after defining `char * str = nullptr;`. Don't get too misled by the syntax for naming templates. Your `testSharedMap` is simply a pointer. A smart pointer, but just a pointer nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

As *[@CruzJean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5141304/cruz-jean)* mentioned in the comments, you need to first allocate memory, before dereferencing it using [`std::shared_ptr::operator->`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*), otherwise(from *cppreference.com*).

> The **behaviour is undefined if the**
>   **stored pointer is nul**l.

For instance, you can do as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

int main() 
{
    // convenience type(alias)
    using Map = std::map<int, int>;
    std::shared_ptr<Map> testSharedMap = std::make_shared<Map>();

    // now you can access the valid memory
    testSharedMap->insert(std::make_pair(0, 1));
    testSharedMap->emplace(1, 1);  // or using `std::map::emplace`

    // print the element in the Map by dereferencing the pointer
    for (const auto [key, value] : *testSharedMap)
        std::cout << key << " " << value << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```